# Sending sensor data from Android app to arduino via USB Serial

Tags: serial, sensors, usb, android, data

I've searched this and have only found solutions for **receiving data FROM Arduino TO android**, **I need the opposite**. I basically need to figure out how to press a button from my android phone that will activate the hardware attached to my arduino mega 2560 AND make it where my arduino can read sensor values from the android device. I'm not an expert with android or arduino, most of the code I already have pertaining to the USB Serial connection is from GitHub.

Comment: you need to figure out how to translate a button press on an Android screen into serial data ... that is not an Arduino question ... try asking at an Android site

Comment: Ill try that, thanks.

Comment: use Blynk and the button on Android screen will work from everywhere